# "including on" vs "including"

Tags: grammar, phrases

I found the following sentence in [uk.businessinsider.com](http://uk.businessinsider.com/eric-schmidt-google-deepmind-one-of-the-greatest-british-success-stories-modern-age-2016-6):

> After being acquired by Google, DeepMind has been put to work implementing artificial intelligence throughout Google, **including on** its search product.

What were the difference if I omitted **on**? It seems more natural to me.

Comment: What is DeepMind, another corporation? btw, I think it can be different as matter of the fact that someone may think **its** means Google's search product has also been employed in the artificial intelligence implementing process. I am not sure. See ***include 2***: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/include. However, In a long context, I think that would be a rare event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example

> including on
>   including

have the same meaning, the DeepMind will be implementing Artificial Intelligence on the suite of Google apps in general and on search in particular.

"On" may have been included by an automatic syntax checker.